# IBM Rational ClearCase/ClearQuest fails to install

Tags: installation, clearcase

I was trying to install IBM Rational ClearCase/ClearQuest on my machine,but it fails with the following error:

**Error during "install" phase:
   Error backing up files from C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\IMShared\native\com.ibm.team.install.win32helper_1.0.0.v200810172210.zip**

The error details as in the log file are as follows:

```
> java.io.IOException: Failed to rename file
> 'C:\ProgramData\IBM\Installation Manager\adapters\native\IBM Rational
> SDLC\com.ibm.sdp.native\backupDirs\10_' to
> 'C:\ProgramData\IBM\Installation Manager\adapters\native\IBM Rational
> SDLC\com.ibm.sdp.native\backupDirs\10'.
```

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be the case with the [latest versions of IM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM26112) (and it was [marked before as a user error](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK65728))

More generally, make sure you [have upgraded your IM (Installation Manager) to the latest version](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27025142) before using it to install an IBM product.

Comment: Thank you. My IM current version is 1.4.1. I will upgrade it.

Comment: @CloudGuan I confirm that IM 1.4.x looks... ancient (August 2010!). 1.8.3 would be better.